# architecture java gwt+jsf2+spring packaging

Tags: java, spring, gwt, jsf-2

I am planning to do a website that has GWT as admin interface, JSF 2 as frontend and spring to  handle business logic.

Basicly. I will have 3 projects:

1. GWT
2. spring (business logic which also might export some web services in the future)
3. JSF 2

In GWT I am planning to have spring context (from the dependend spring-project) and use it to connect to database?

1. Is this possible to create 3 projects in eclipse, refer as dependencies them and then create an EAR that contains all of these?
2. What happens to user session? stored in GWT and JSF 2?
3. Is it a good architecture? how can be this done somehow else?
4. How do I package those? all war files? or jar? in a single ear... or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question because I will give more details for the next guys that will want to do the same thing I do:

In Eclipse:

1. Create new Java EE Application normaly with 3 or how many modules you want
2. Add new GWT project
3. Add the existing GWT project to the Java EE descriptor (to be added in ear)
4. In project builder you should have this:
   [image]
5. Compile the GWT Apllication once:
   [image]
6. After you deployed your application in `glassfish` access your website with chrome at this URL: `http://localhost:8080/Admin/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

What you need to know:

- Servlets are hot deployed
- Any modification you do on servlets will change server part
- Any modification you do on GWT Application `google chrome` plugin will take care of it

My environment:

- `JDK 1.7.0_11`
- `Eclipse 4.2 Java EE` (`+ GWT Plugin`, `+ Spring plugin`)
- `Glassfish 3.1.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

First of all why do you want to use two different client side technologies together (`JSF2` and `GWT`)?
I would rather stick to one of them.

Saying that: Yes, it is possible to have 3 different projects. Actually the recommended way (at least with `GWT` and `Spring` or any other backend) is to have them in separate projects.

> Is this possible to create 3 projects in eclipse, refer as
>   dependencies them and then create an EAR that  contains all of these?

Well at least with GWT you usually can't access the backend/database directly (not sure about JSF2). You have to use some kind of communication protocol (`RequestBuilder`, `RequestFactory`, `GWT-RPC`, `REST`)
You can have shared classes (in package `xxx.shared`) that can be referenced by both your `GWT` and your  `Spring` application (that is normally used by `GWT-RPC` or `RequestFactory`)

> What happens to user session? stored in GWT and JSF 2?

There is nothing special about user sessions. 
GWT and JSF communicate via HTTP requests with the backend. So the same thing that applies to normal HTTP requests also applies to GWT/JSF2 requests.

> Is it a good architecture? how can be this done somehow else?

It depends on what you want to achieve. As mentioned before I would rather stick to one client side technology (`GWT` or `JSF2`) rather than using both of them.

> How do I package those? all war files? or jar? in a single ear... or?

GWT compiles down to javascript which is included in your host file. 
So you usually create one **WAR** or **EAR** file that gets deployed to the application server.

Comment: Hi, I want to write my admin interface in GWT and the client side (the anonymous users visit) in JSF 2... don't you find it a good approach?

Comment: why do you want to do that? Which kind of benefit do you see in using two different client side technologies? 
Why not stick **either** to GWT or JSF2 for both (admin and anonymous view)? 
Using two different client side technologies add just another layer of complexity another system you have to know about. I would use whatever you are most comfortable with.

Comment: well.. I want everything on ajax in admin... and I want on refresh on client side for crawlers... so that google can index my website... using GWT I don't think my website will be indexed... am I correct?

Comment: You can use the [crawler](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/CrawlerSupport) library of GWTP to add crawler support your GWT app. And with JSF2 you can also do AJAX requests

Comment: but.. is it possible to add all these 3 in an ear? I want to make a separate project where I can write spring and another where I can gwt and another where I can write jsf... and connect all of them without RMI or webservices or sockets or anything... and how do you make this projects in eclipse? just make them dependent?

Comment: yes you can have all of them in one EAR. For these kind of dependencies I would use a dependency framework like maven.